# Adding common library files to Flex Builder?

Tags: flexbuilder

So I'm playing around with an ActionScript library (Flare, to be specific) in Flex Builder 3.  I'd like to have this functionality available to all projects in my workspace without having to copy it to every one.  What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but you can link to a folder or file from within a project.  You right-click on the project, and choose "New <whatever>" and click on the Advanced button to access the link functionality.  From there, you can use the file navigator to choose a file or folder.  Afterwards it will show up in the project properties under the build path (the tab for library paths).

We use this because we split off a large chunk of our code into a separate library project, but that code still references a ton of image files in the original projects root directory.  So we create a link to that image directory and all is well again.  Maybe this will help you also.

Answer (score 0):

We have a shared folder "flex" that we place our common libs. In the properties for the project, under flex build path, set the library path to your location for flare.